# ASP.NET MVC + razor: multiple dropdowns with same options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model, which has a list of objects, which all should have an editable dropdown list. For example, consider a book library with following definition:

```
class Category
{
    int id;
    int name;
}

class Book
{
    int id;
    string name;
    int categoryId;
}

class Library
{
    List <Book> books;
}
```

So a library has a list of books, and each book has a category. In UI, the category is selected from a dropdown list, so there one dropdown per book. The list of categories is same for all books. How could I make this work with razor views? When trying to bind a dropdown to specific index in the book list with html helper, the index variable uses it's last value, so all dropdowns get bound to the same book. Also, how would adding/removing books be handled?

Simplified version of view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Books.Count; ++i)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Books[i].CategoryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Edit: The problem seems to be that the dropdown lists don't get the initial value. If I change them and save the list, the correct values are sent back to backend. Any idea, what could cause this?

Comment: What have you tried? Include the code for your views.

Comment: What kind of data stored inside `ViewBag.Categories`? Are you want to reuse same option list with different default selected option for multiple dropdownlist bound to each `books` list indexes?

Comment: Categories is of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>. Yes, that's what I would kinda want to achieve. Or actually, it's not a different default value, but just selected value, which can of course be different for different books. Can there be type problem? Id is of type int and SelectListItem.Value is a string. On the other hand, the binding seems to otherwise work, just the initial value is not set.

Comment: One more thing: did `Books[i].CategoryId` values already provided from controller action before user selecting value from dropdownlist? If those `CategoryId` have any value before sending to view, I think you could set `SelectListItem.Selected` property based on comparison of `Id` property against `CategoryId`.

Comment: Yes, Books[i].CategoryId is set. Hmm... I'm using the same select list (created in controller) for all books, but they are supposed to have different initial values. Also one thing to notice is, that this works, if CategoryId is a property of Model instead, and shared by all books. Having it as an array somehow messes things up.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, although not very elegant one. I'm creating a new dropdown for each book, and set the selected value in those dropdowns:

```
DropDownListFor(model => model.Books[i].CategoryId, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories).Select(x => new SelectListItem(){Value = x.Value, Text = x.Text, Selected = Model.Books[i].CategoryId.ToString() == x.Value}))
```